# Discuss convergence of the series $\sum \left\{e-(1+\frac{1}{k})^k \right\}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is probably a pretty elementary problem but I was struggling to show the convergence/divergence of the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\{ e-(1+\frac{1}{k})^k \right\}.$$

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estimate the error term.  It turns out to be bounded below by order $1/k$, so the sum diverges by the comparison test.

Indeed, for $x\to 0^+$, we have
$$
\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}{x}\to-\frac{1}{2}e\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
so $e-(1+\frac1k)^k\approx\frac{e}{2k}$.

**Addendum**
One way to show the limit ($\dagger$) is to look at
$$
\log(1+x)^{1/x}=x^{-1}(x-\frac12 x^2+\dots)=1-\frac12 x+\dots
$$
so $(1+x)^{1/x}=\exp(1-\frac12x+\dots)=e\cdot\exp(-\frac12 x+\dots)=e-\frac12 ex+O(x^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry for asking really stupid questions but how would you show that the error term is bounded by $1/k$?

Comment: added derivation of the limit and corrected the factor of $e$ missing from the first post.  Then it is just using $1/k$ as a particular sequence $\to 0+$ to get the "error term" $e-(1+1/k)^k\geq(\frac{e}{2}-\epsilon)\frac{1}{k}$ for all sufficiently large $k$.